# Use destructuring to assign value to object property

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I've used destructuring in various instances of my ES6 code but today I tried shortening a model instance declaration and it's not quite working in node. Basically, I'm pulling data from the YouTube Data API and storing it in my MongoDB instance. Accordingly, I created an object from the thumbnail portion of the response like so:

```
thumbnailData = {
      smallWidth: element.snippet.thumbnails.default.width,
      smallHeight: element.snippet.thumbnails.default.height,
      smallURL: element.snippet.thumbnails.default.url,
      medWidth: element.snippet.thumbnails.medium.width,
      medHeight: element.snippet.thumbnails.medium.height,
      medURL: element.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url,
      highWidth: element.snippet.thumbnails.high.width,
      highHight: element.snippet.thumbnails.high.height,
      highURL: element.snippet.thumbnails.high.url
    }
```

And I have a Mongoose schema like so:

```
const ThumbnailSchema = new Schema({
  smallWidth: Number,
  smallHeight: Number,
  smallURL: String,
  medWidth: Number,
  medHeight: Number,
  medURL: String,
  highWidth: Number,
  highHight: Number,
  highURL: String
});
const Thumbnail = mongoose.model('thumbnail', ThumbnailSchema);
```

So I was trying to do something like this in my declaration:

```
let thumbs = new Thumbnail;
({ thumbs.smallWidth, thumbs.smallHeight, thumbs.smallURL } = thumbnailData);
```

But node.js throws a simple 'Unexpect token .' above my use of . in the left-hand side. Ideas if this is even possible? It's just killing me to have to write the object out in such long form but I can leave it if needs be because it does work. It seems much like the syntax below so not sure what the difference is, thanks.

```
var a, b;
({ a, b } = {a: 1, b: 2});
```

Comment: The difference is that `{a, b}` are variable names while `{ thumbs.… }` are property accesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't destructure an object that way, Javascript recognizes the dots as property accesses, like @Bergi commented. One way you could minimize repetition however, is by destructuring `default`, `medium`, `high` out of the `thumbnails` property:

```
const { 'default': dflt, medium, high } = element.snippet.thumbnails;

let thumbs = new Thumbnail({
  smallWidth: dflt.width,
  smallHeight: dflt.height,
  smallURL: dflt.url,
  medWidth: medium.width,
  medHeight: medium.height,
  medURL: medium.url,
  highWidth: high.width,
  highHight: high.height,
  highURL: high.url
});
```

Comment: This actually won't work since default is a reserved keyword in JS, attempted it and it threw an error. I did use this style however by just removing the default thumbnail since it doesn't fit my use case (too small at 90x120)

Comment: You're right, sorry I didn't test my code. Just fixed it, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
({ thumbs.smallWidth, thumbs.smallHeight, thumbs.smallURL } = thumbnailData);
```

will not work. Because the Js interpreter is not expecting the token `.` in the left hand that is considered as a property access. To make it work, you can use rather

```
({ a: thumbs.smallWidth, b:thumbs.smallHeight, c:thumbs.smallURL } = thumbnailData);
```

This will assign the value to your new object. Here is a working snippet:

```js
var data = {a: "a", b: "b"};

( {a: data.a, b: data.b} = {a: 1, b : 2})

console.log(data.a)
```

Comment: The first snippet is not ES6 anyway. There's no reason why any engine would support it.

Comment: I don't mean the first one. For definitely, it is not going to work. I am rather talking about the second one @Bergi

Comment: I don't see why you are saying that ES6 is not yet supported, or that it would not work in V8. It definitely does.

Comment: The semicolon has nothing to do with the first statement not working and the second one working.

Comment: The first snippet in your answer does not work regardless with or without the semicolon, so I don't understand why you mentioned it in your comments. Your explanation with the dot is correct. There is no downvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162124/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Object.assign(thumbs, (({ smallWidth, smallHeight, smallURL}) => ({smallWidth, smallHeight, smallURL}))(thumbnailData));
```

A small IIFE that uses parameter destructuring would work. Or old stylish:

```
 for(var key of ["smallWidth", "smallHeight", "smallURL"])
  thumbs[key] = thumbnailData[key];
```